# (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics-api

i have issue with google api service account i have done successfull authentication and got the access token. when i try to run the query it shows error

> Warning: You need to set Client ID, Email address and the location of
>   the Key from the Google API console:
>   http://developers.google.com/consoleThere wan a general error : Error
>   calling GE T
>    (403)
>   User does  not have any Google Analytics account.

i have multiple websites and multiple accounts in it. the google account is an admin account please check the code below.

```
   $key_file_location = 'key path';
   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->setApplicationName("name");
   $client->setClientId($client_id);

   if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
     $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
   }
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$client->setAccessType('offline_access');
$client->getAccessToken();
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$analytics_id   = 'ga:xxxxxx';
$lastWeek       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
$today          = date('Y-m-d');
try {
    $results = $service->data_ga->get($analytics_id, $lastWeek, $today,'ga:visits');
    echo '<b>Number of visits this week:</b> ';
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Don't be disappointed if nobody answers this questions. You leave it to your readers to fully debug the problem, this is probably too much. Try to narrow down your problem a bit. If you have luck, somebody just sees the solution ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node: Google Analytics data via service account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960250/node-google-analytics-data-via-service-account)

Comment: The answer on that question will show you how to give the service account access to your google analytics data.

Comment: Dalmo is correct you need to add the "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL>@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
to the Google Accounts you want it to have access to.

Comment: i have given all credential available in api console. sorry to mention in code.
i have tried same thing in client side api. successfully implemented and worked well. but i need to run this thing as service